# What control model would I use for implementing a toolbox control like Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

I need to implement a toolbox control similar to the toolbox exposed in visual studio.

I can think of several ways to accomplish this, but none of them seem right.

The best solution I can come up with is implementation a stack panel of list boxes.

How would I do this to most closely match functionality and behavior of the VS toolbox?

[image]

Comment: Why not use a TreeView?

Comment: What does 'easiest way' mean?  Easiest to code in Xaml? Easiest to wire up to commands in a VM?

Comment: This is a TreeView no point in even bothering with something else.

Comment: @GarryVass, I made an edit to clarify that I want to implement whatever will match the closest to the Visual Studio toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internals of Visual Studio, but the toolbox gives the experience of a box-standard TreeView control.

The item template is most likely constructed from a container class that looks like this...

```
public class ToolbarItemInfo
{
    public string FamilyName { get; private set; }
    public Image ItemIcon { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public Action<ToolbarItemInfo> OnFired { get; private set; }
}
```

... where 'FamilyName' is something like 'Common WPF Controls' so that the manager knows where to put each item.  They all share a common tooltip strategy and context menu.

It is my *GUESS* that Visual Studio is using the Event Aggregator to fire off commands on the tree items.  That's a guess, but I wouldn't be surprised if they used something else.    The class I posted uses an Action delegate because I didn't want to drag the whole Prism thing into the answer if it's not called for.

The tear-off window comes from a home-grown component developed in-house.